# user error (Pattern match failure in do expression) with PostgreSQL.Simple

Tags: haskell, postgresql-simple

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feed (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (id > 0),
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  url TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

My code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Database.PostgreSQL.Simple

hello :: IO String
hello = do
  conn <- connectPostgreSQL ""
  [Only i] <- query_ conn "SELECT url FROM feed WHERE id = 1"
  return i

main :: IO ()
main = hello >>= print
```

My error:

```
user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at src/Main.hs:8:3-10)
```

My questions:

- How do I fix this error?
- How could I get a more informative error message?

**Update:** I connected to the wrong database and therefor my assumption about the result set was wrong. It contained zero lines instead of one line and thus it tried to match `[]` against `[Only i]`. I found it out by executing the query in ghci:

```
:set -XOverloadedStrings
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
do;  conn <- connectPostgreSQL "" ;query_ conn "SELECT url FROM feed WHERE id = 1"
```

Comment: What do you get when your use `i <- query_ conn "SELECT url FROM feed WHERE id = 1"`? In that case you can inspect what value you obtained and why it is not matching.

Comment: if you do `i <- query_ conn "select ..."` change the `hello :: IO String` to `hello :: IO [String]`